# Using values of variables in on-the-spot shell commands (using ``)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that for-loops over input to get a number and string. If I want to test the number in the loop, can I cut the looped-over variable to get the number? For example, something like:

```
for line in input
do
num=`cut -f1 $line`
...
done
```

If not, how else can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
num=`cut -f1 $line`
```

You can do:

```
num=$(echo "$line" | cut -f1)
```

OR else using awk:

```
num=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< $line)
```

OR using pure BASH:

```
num=${line%% *}
```

Your command `cut -f1 $line` will try to cut first column from a file named as `$line`.

Comment: @twalberg: Thanks so much, adding to my answer. I always forget these nice BASH internal features.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want instead ?

```
 while read -r number str
 do
   echo $number;
   echo $str;
 done < input
```